# How can I get the column names of a table referred by a dblink?

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

I am new to oracle. I have a table referred using a dblink, say MY_TABLE@MY_DBLINK. Suppose MY_TABLE has columns like COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2. How can I write a query to return the column names?

I tried to use DESCRIBE MY_TABLE@MY_DBLINK. But it is showing the error as "ERROR: object MY_TABLE does not exist". But I am able to display the contents of the same table using SELECT.

Comment: It is interesting, but at least in Oracle 10g+ the SQL+ tool can successfully show the result of the `DESCRIBE MY_TABLE@MY_DBLINK`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select column_name
  from all_tab_columns@MY_DBLINK
 where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```